# List of Opened MDI Child in Toolbar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mdi, mdichild

Is there a way to manage my opened MDI Child windows in a toolbar, my project manage lot of windows and the user dont know if some window is open and then open a new one (i also need that the user can open more that one window with works fine) i just one something like a toolbar or something where user can see all open mdi child and when click, focus that window.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you using windows forms ?

Comment: For an actual MDI application you'd setup a MenuStrip and assign the MdiWindowListItem property accordingly.  See [How to: Create an MDI Window List with MenuStrip (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171654%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  If you want to display the list some other way you'll have to build it from scratch...